# Mysql Copy Database From Sql Statement

Tags: java, mysql

I am attempting to create a test database (based off of my production db) at runtime, but rather than have to maintain an exact duplicate test db i'd like to copy the entire data structure of my production db at runtime and then when I close the test database, drop the entire database.

I assume I will be using statements such as:

```
CREATE DATABASE test //to create the test db
CREATE TABLE test.sampleTable LIKE production.sampleTable //to create each table
```

And when I am finished with the test db, calling a close method will run something like:

```
DROP DATABASE test //delete the database and all its tables
```

But how do I go about automatically finding all the tables within the production database without having to manually write them out. The idea is that I can manipulate my production db without having to be concerned with maintaining the structure identically within the test db.

Would a stored procedure be necessary in this case? Some sample code on how to achieve something like this would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than maintaining the structure in both places, you might do this with [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html), so all changes to prod (data and schema) will immediately synchronize to test.

Comment: The MySQL "SHOW TABLES" command lists the non-temporary tables in a given database

Comment: Wouldn't replication copy the database, its tables, as well as all the data within those tables though? My test db should have empty tables, I just want the table structure to be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was as follows:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TEST_DB = "CREATE DATABASE test";
private static final String SQL_PROD_TABLES = "SHOW TABLES IN production";

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_CREATE_TEST_DB);

SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(SQL_PROD_TABLES);
while(result.next()) {
    String tableName = result.getString(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(1)); //Retrieves table name from column 1            
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE test2." + tableName + " LIKE production." + tableName); //Create new table in test2 based on production structure
}
```

This is using Spring to simplify the database connection etc, but the real magic is in the SQL statements. As mentioned by D Mac, this will not copy foreign key constraints, but that can be achieved by running another SQL statement and parsing the results.

Answer (score 0):

In your scripting language, you call "SHOW TABLES" on the database you want to copy. Reading that result set a row at a time, your program puts the name of the table into a variable (let's call it $tablename) and can generate the sql: "CREATE TABLE test.$tablename LIKE production.$tablename". Iterate through the result set and you're done.

(You won't get foreign key constraints that way, but maybe you don't need those. If you do, you can run "SHOW CREATE TABLE $tablename" and parse the results to pick out the constraints.)

I don't have a code snippet for java, but here is one for perl that you could treat as pseudo-code:

```
$ref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SHOW TABLES");
unless(defined ($ref)){
        print "Nothing found\n";
} else {
        foreach my $row_ref (@{$ref}){
                push(@tables, $row_ref->[0]);
        }
}
```

The foreach statement iterates over the result set in an array reference returned by the database interface library. The push statement puts the first element of the current row of the result set into an array variable @tables. You'd be using the database library appropriate for your language of choice.

Comment: How do I put the name of the table in a variable? I am using Java.

Comment: @ryandlf, I edited my answer to show a snippet in perl - sorry, I don't know the database interface libraries in java.

Answer (score 0):

If the database driver you are using supports it, you can use [DatabaseMetaData#getTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to get the list of tables for a schema. You can get access to DatabaseMetaData from [Connection#getMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I would use mysqldump : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

It will produce a file containing all the sql commands needed to replicate the prod database